# Do I have define my own endpoint to support CORS OPTIONS request

Tags: .net, rest, cors

I have a REST Service written in vb.net running on IIS that has a number of `<WebGet>` defined and one that supports POST with a `<WebInvoke(Method:="POST")>`.  Now I know that browsers make Preflight checks, by making a pre-call with the `OPTIONS` method (to see what Methods are supported), but what I don't know is, do I have to define and `<WebInvoke(Method:="OPTIONS)>` or is this just dealt with by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` to my web.config, I can find lots of articles about how to enable CORS and I don't think I need to add another `<WebInvoke>`, but I need some guidance.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it in the web.config similar to below:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

or you can have it like the one mentioned here if you have cors module inside:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: Yes I know about adding it that way, I was checking that by adding that to my web.config, I don't need to write any additional <WebInvoke> statements to deal with the incoming OPTIONS calls I will receive on the POST endpoints.

Comment: My assumption is that you don't need but you need to allow OPTIONS as well. But you can try and see. Let me know if its otherwise.